# Cursor based pagination in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am planning to build cursor-based pagination APIs for the data in Cassandra.

Does Cassandra Java driver support cursor-based pagination? Or what would be a good approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please review this DataStax document as it talks about large result sets and how to save "state" to continue where you left off:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.2/manual/paging/

In particular, the piece I believe that discusses what you're trying to do:

"Saving and reusing the paging state
Sometimes it is convenient to save the paging state in order to restore it later. For example, consider a stateless web service that displays a list of results with a link to the next page. When the user clicks that link, we want to run the exact same query, except that the iteration should start where we stopped on the previous page."